# Blogpost on what Stack Exchange has changed in its backend?

Tags: discussion, technology

I'm very anxious to see what all technologies that SE has changed underneath. As the site seems very clean UI (front-end) and superfast (back-end?) now compared to yesterday?

Is there a blogpost about the changes?

Comment: Which site are you talking about, exactly?

Comment: stackoverflow to be exact. And impressed with it!!

Comment: All that changed was the design (and if you follow MSO, it got the treatment in November). If you are seeing any speed changes (would love it if you could quantify them) - probably on your end or your ISP end.

Comment: Re *"the site seems very clean UI (front-end)"*: That didn't age well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot going on beneath the SE sites. Take a look at the new [performance page](https://stackexchange.com/performance) (which is currently 'work in progress'):

> [image]

Also read the FAQ question [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network), and the [original 2008 blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/) about it.